# Merging many arrays from Promise.all

Tags: javascript, arrays

When `Promise.all` completes it returns an array of arrays that contain data. In my case the arrays are just numbers:

```
[
    [ 1, 4, 9, 9 ],
    [ 4, 4, 9, 1 ],
    [ 6, 6, 9, 1 ]
]
```

The array can be any size.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
let nums = []
data.map(function(_nums) {
    _nums.map(function(num) {
        nums.push(num)
    })
})
```

Is there an alternative way of doing this? Does `lodash` have any functions that are able to do this?

Comment: You could concat them all? `_.concat([], promise_results)` might do it?

Comment: As a general note: if you're not using the return value of `map`, you shouldn't be using `map`. If you just want to iterate, use `forEach`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

ES2019 introduced [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) which significantly simplifies this to:

```js
const nums = data.flat();
```

```js
const data = [
  [ 1, 4, 9, 9 ],
  [ 4, 4, 9, 1 ],
  [ 6, 6, 9, 1 ]
];

const nums = data.flat();

console.log(nums);
```

---

<sub>Original Answer</sub>

Use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
data.reduce(function (arr, row) {
  return arr.concat(row);
}, []);
```

Or alternatively, `concat` and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```js
Array.prototype.concat.apply([], data);
```

Answer (score 9):

I would do as follows;

```js
var a = [
    [ 1, 4, 9, 9 ],
    [ 4, 4, 9, 1 ],
    [ 6, 6, 9, 1 ]
],
    b = [].concat(...a)

console.log(b)
```

Comment: Thanks Man, your solution made my day:-)

Comment: b = [ ...a ]  would also be a possibility

Answer (score 7):

You actually don't need any sort of library to do it, you can use `concat` with `apply`:

```
Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then((arrayOfArrays) => {
    return [].concat.apply([], arrayOfArrays);
});
```

If you are using lodash, though, you can use `_.flatten(arrayOfArrays)` for the same effect.

Comment: Quick question, is this prototype chaining when using `contact.apply(...)`?

Answer (score 5):

If using async/await, to expand on @Retsam's answer, you can do it like so

```
const mergedArray = []
  .concat
  .apply([], await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promiseN]));
```

A real world example I did using the AWS SDK, getting a list of usernames from multiple IAM user groups

```
const users = await getActiveUsersByGroup(['group1', 'group2'])

async function getActiveUsersByGroup(groups = []) {
  getUsersByGroupPromises = groups.map(group => getUsersByGroup(group));
  const users = []
    .concat
    .apply([], await Promise.all(getUsersByGroupPromises)) // Merge (concat) arrays
    .map(users => users.UserName); // Construct new array with just the usernames
  
  return users;
}

async function getUsersByGroup(group) {
  const params = {
    GroupName: group,
    MaxItems: 100     // Default
  };
  const { Users: users } = await iam.getGroup(params).promise();

  return users;
}
```

Comment: Kudos for the complex real example

Comment: if you are using TypeScript it will infer the `[].concat.apply` as `never[]` , you can do `([] as string[]).concat.apply`

Answer (score 0):

In that case, we are returning objects instead of arrays as a response, so we can assign it to one single object like that:
The spread operator `...` is used to spread the array of objects into separate arguments for the `Object.assign()` method. This is a shorthand way of merging the array of objects into a single object.

```
const allPromiseResponse = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {c: 3, d: 4}, {e: 5, f: 6}];

Object.assign({}, ...allPromiseResponse)
```

I hope it can be useful to someone